# MySQL select sum with group by and empty values

Tags: mysql, sql

let's assume I have a store which is open from 10 till 15 and the sales will save in the following table with time stamp:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
| store_id | sales_date          | sales_amount  |
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|        1 | 2017-11-03 10:32:44 | 100.00        | 
|        1 | 2017-11-03 10:33:49 | 150.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-03 11:08:24 | 120.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-03 13:33:57 | 200.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-03 12:37:34 | 100.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-03 15:23:49 | 200.00        |
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I would like to display a chart using chart.js with the range from 10 til 15.

I tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT store_id, HOUR(sales_date) as group_hour, sum(sales_amount) as sales_sum 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY store_id, group_hour
```

My **current** result is

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| store_id | group_hour  | sales_sum     |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|        1 | 10          | 250.00        | 
|        1 | 11          | 120.00        |
|        1 | 13          | 200.00        |
|        2 | 12          | 100.00        |
|        2 | 15          | 200.00        |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

My **expected** result is

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| store_id | group_hour  | sales_sum     |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|        1 | 10          | 250.00        | 
|        1 | 11          | 120.00        |
|        1 | 12          | 0.00          |
|        1 | 13          | 200.00        |
|        1 | 14          | 0.00          |
|        1 | 15          | 0.00          |
|        2 | 10          | 0.00          |
|        2 | 11          | 0.00          |
|        2 | 12          | 100.00        |
|        2 | 13          | 0.00          |
|        2 | 14          | 0.00          |
|        2 | 15          | 200.00        |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Is there a chance to do this with MySQL?

Comment: join it with a table that contains only the  hours you want

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT b.store_id, b.group_hour, IFNULL(sales_sum, 0) AS sales_sum
FROM 
(
 SELECT store_id, HOUR(sales_date) as group_hour, sum(sales_amount) as sales_sum 
 FROM sales 
 GROUP BY store_id, group_hour
) a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT store_id
   FROM sales
  ) all_stores
  CROSS JOIN
  (
   SELECT 10 as group_hour
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 11
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 12
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 13
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 14
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 15
  ) all_hours
) b
ON a.store_id = b.store_id AND a.group_hour = b.group_hour
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I am using RIGHT OUTER JOIN with the table that contains all stores and all hours (from 10 to 15).

Comment: This works like a charm :-) But now, there is another requirement from my client, that he will be able to filter by date range and also by month.

So instead group_hour (with a defined range from 10-15) I need a group_day (e.g. 2017-10-30 till 2017-11-04) and also a group_day based on the selected month (e.g. october).

Should I update my question or start a new question?

Comment: I would recommend to create a different question.