# PHP MySQL sum between two cols not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am kinda stuck while making a dynamic graph with PHP.
Here is the code:

```
$arrlength = count($ages);for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    
    $query = $con->query("SELECT SUM(Amount) AS AmountTotal FROM Col WHERE Type!=1 AND client_id = $client_id AND (StartAge<$ages[$x] OR Start=$ages[$x]) AND (EndAge>$ages[$x] OR EndAge=$ages[$x])");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
           
            $Total = $row['AmountTotal'];
    
        }     
    }
            if(!empty($Total)){echo" $Total,";}else { echo" 0,";}
        
}
```

Graph X-axis is Age and Y is the Sum of Amount.
Their multiple entries in the data.

The data is:

| StartAge | EndAge | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 5 | 7 | 10 |
| 7 | 9 | 10 |

Ages Array count from 1 to 10 so,
the Data i wanna output as ( 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 0).

Currently, I am getting 0 for all values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47097763/2943403  and several other similar pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would run less queries and have a more efficient process if you considered summarizing your query combining your logical expressions (i.e. using <= instead of < then = or by using BETWEEN) and a group by. Using PHP you may consider generating part of your query as follows:

1. Step 1 - Using php to generate a sub query with all the ages

```php
$agesTable="( ";
foreach($ages as $age){
    $agesTable.=" SELECT $age as age UNION ALL ";
}
$agesTable.=" SELECT NULL as age) ages";
```

2. Creating complete SQL Query to run

I am assuming `$client_id` is not a value received from a client facing application eg web/mobile app, in that case you should consider SQL injection and using prepared statements when running your query. Which there are numerous articles and S/O questions addressing this.

```php
$combinedQuery = "SELECT ages.age as Age, SUM(COALESCE(Col.Amount,0)) as AmountTotal FROM $agesTable LEFT JOIN  Col ON ages.age BETWEEN Col.StartAge AND Col.EndAge AND Type!=1 AND client_id = $client_id WHERE ages.age IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 1";
```

3. Step 3 - Run your query

```php
$results = []; //store all your graph data as
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 

        if(empty($row['Age']))continue; //optional - to ignore null groups

        //append data to your array of results
        array_push($results,[
            //Below I use 'Age' and 'Total' as my array keys but you may also use X and Y instead
            'Age'=>$row['Age'], //extract the age or your 'X' value
            'Total'=>$row['AmountTotal'] //extract the total or your 'Y' value
        ]);   
        //instead of appending the data for your chart to an array to be used later, you could continue with your current approach and output it here.
    }     
}
```

Your results array would look like this based on the values you have for ages.

```
[
    [
       'Age'=>1,
       'Total'=>10
    ],
    [
       'Age'=>2,
       'Total'=>10
    ],
    ...etc
]
```

I have replicated this solution and the generated query using php and a db-fiddle. You will see the complete results below

Test PHP Code

```php
<?php

$ages = [];
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)$ages[]=$i;

$agesTable="( ";
foreach($ages as $age){
    $agesTable.=" SELECT $age as age UNION ALL ";
}
$agesTable.=" SELECT NULL as age) ages";
$client_id=1;
$combinedQuery = "SELECT ages.age as Age, SUM(COALESCE(Col.Amount,0)) as AmountTotal FROM $agesTable LEFT JOIN  Col ON ages.age BETWEEN Col.StartAge AND Col.EndAge AND Type!=1 AND client_id = $client_id WHERE ages.age IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 1";
echo $combinedQuery;
```

DB Fiddle Output using `$combinedQuery` output above

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Col (
  `StartAge` INTEGER,
  `EndAge` INTEGER,
  `Amount` INTEGER,
  `client_id` INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  `Type` INTEGER DEFAULT 2
);

INSERT INTO Col
  (`StartAge`, `EndAge`, `Amount`)
VALUES
  ('1', '9', '10'),
  ('5', '7', '10'),
  ('7', '9', '10');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    ages.age as Age, 
    SUM(COALESCE(Col.Amount,0)) as AmountTotal 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 1 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 8 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 9 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT 10 as age UNION ALL 
  SELECT NULL as age) ages 
LEFT JOIN 
    Col ON ages.age BETWEEN Col.StartAge AND Col.EndAge AND 
           Type!=1 AND client_id = 1 
WHERE ages.age IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 1;
```

| Age | AmountTotal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 20 |
| 6 | 20 |
| 7 | 30 |
| 8 | 20 |
| 9 | 20 |
| 10 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pYhwqTk4F1mUFTm9LJe8my/6)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation and a simple solution. And yes $client_id is not from the client side.

Comment: @HamzaAfzal After noticing a few php typos and taking another look at your sample expected results. I have updated the answer. Please also see a sample php script and db-fiddle with working solution. Let me know if this works as expected.

Comment: I had those typos fixed. Thank you for your help its also solves my code complexity issue.